# how to rename class in Json schema response

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I have class and I am generating schema from it.

```
    public class CreateDemoRequest
    {
     [JsonIgnore]
     public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "models")]
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "models")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "models"), NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public DemoRequestModel[] Models { get; set; }
    }

    public class DemoRequestModel{

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "demoField ")]
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "demoField ")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "demoField ", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string DemoField { get; set; }
    }
```

above is class and below is code to generate schema.

```
     JSchema schemaResult = new JSchema();
     JSchemaGenerator schemaGen = _schemaGenerator.Value;
     schemaResult = schemaGen.Generate(typeof(CreateDemoRequest));
```

and getting response as below.

```
     {
      "_schema": {
         "definitions": {
          "DemoRequestModel": {
           "properties": {
            "demoField": {
             "type": [
              "string",
              "null"
             ]
            }
           }
          }
         },
         "properties": {
          "models": {
           "type": "array",
            "items": {
             "$ref": "#/definitions/DemoRequestModel"
             }
            }
           }
          }
         }
```

**how I will get "models" instead of "DemoRequestModel" under definitions??**
tried using data contract but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few issues, including incorrect usage of `JsonProperty` for `Models` for example and not calling `JSchemaGenerator.Generate` correctly using `typeof(...)`.

Those issues fixed, why do you want to get `models` instead of `DemoRequestModel`?

This gives you what you want but why?

```
public class CreateDemoRequest
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "models", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public models[] Models { get; set; }
}

public class models
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "demoField", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string DemoField { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "models": {
      "type": [
        "object",
        "null"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "demoField": {
          "type": [
            "string",
            "null"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "models": {
      "type": [
        "array",
        "null"
      ],
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/models"
      }
    }
  }
}
```